# No response from poloniex api

Tags: android, ios, api, poloniex

The issue I'm facing now is related to poloniex public API. For some reason I get the error on web browser on ask reCAPTCHA option.

```
[3463] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 403 for https://poloniex.com/public?command=returnChartData&currencyPair=BTC_XMR&start=1405699200&end=9999999999&period=14400
```

Comment: There is a Space in the URL after `BTC_XMR`, is that from copy/pasting or could that be the problem?

Comment: I tried the get request given by you and it's working fine for me on both firefox and chrome. On firefox, it does'nt work the first time since poloniex does a browser compatibility and CAPTHA check, however, I could get response the second time. Worked the first time itself on chrome. Could you please give more details on the exact issue you are facing ?

Comment: I get a 403 when I fire this request from POSTMAN, and this makes sense because poloniex does not recognize this as a browser. Can you try this request using a different browser ?

Comment: @mhutter I try that ,this another issue.

Comment: @mhutter I tried that. Seems like this is another issue.

Comment: @SaurabhGour i got results on all browser before. Once CAPTCHA check is added there is no response in Android and IOS

Comment: I hope you are doing this manually by pasting the get request in a browser of your mobile and then performing reCAPTHA check if required. I tried this request in my android mobile on both UC Browser and Chrome and could get a response for both. Please check this on a different device to make sure your IP is not getting blocked by poloniex. I'm not sure if this would make a difference, but also try clearing your browsing data.

Comment: @SaurabhGour I got response on all browser.now i facing issue on Android and IOS mobile devices.

Comment: Sounds to me like you get blocked by Poloniex, probably for doing too many requests?

Comment: @mhutter yes.I checked to use another IP address,there to faced same issue.this is another issue.

Comment: Even i am facing the same issue from last month. If we hit the public api manually, its asking for a security check first time. Once we clear that, cache is getting updated and following hits doesn't ask for security check. But if we hit via code, it's just returning the security check response instead of the actual values. Did you got any fix for this?

Answer (score 0):

In theorie, API methods are call from a code ( and not directly as a normal webpage on a web browser.)

When you write code to make api call, generaly (except a specific requirement ) you did not setup the "User-Agent".

In your case the User Agent is added on your web browser side.

So it is possible that Poloniex double check "User-Agent" in order to ban not conventional browser ... probably to avoid DDOS.

Last news has confirmed that some fake poloniex android app was stealing API secret and key, so it is potentialy a security feature setup in response to this treat by Poloniex to avoid definitly that "malware" android app could act on wallet without the user permission.

If it is not relative to anti-ddos process it could be relative to mobile ISP applying filter or doing MIM for security.